# SimpleSAMLphp : installation localhost with Wamp

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, simplesamlphp

I try to instal SimpleSAMLphp on my localhost with WampServer so i follow the tutorial on this page : https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install

But when i finish and try to acces to the homepage of my instalation i get this message : "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I know it's come from the configuration of my apache but i don't understand how to fix it.

I put this line in my file httpd.con :

```
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName localhost:80
        DocumentRoot /var/www/localhost:80

        Alias /simplesaml /var/simplesamlphp/www
</VirtualHost>
```

and i put all the file that i dowload on https://simplesamlphp.org at the path C:/wamp/www/var/simplesamlphp/

I try to change my configuration of my file httpd.con but i still have the same error.

================ Second post ==============

After many time and try of differents configuration i still don't understand why it don't work but i have new elements.

I return to the base file httpd.con i just uncomment the line : `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` and i add in the file httpd-vhosts.conf this lines :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost:80
        DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/<myWebSite>"

        Alias /simplesaml c:/wamp/www/var/simplesamlphp/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

But now when i go on the page localhost/simplesaml i have this message : `page in inaccessible`

So i try to exchange the index file at the path : `C:\wamp\www\var\simplesamlphp\www`

And the new file work (if i try just to do an echo "toto")

So i'm lost.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try checking your PHP version.